# Split a list into multiple sublists in Java

Tags: java

I have an input as below. This is a String.

```
[[1641771267063,-0.63,-0.35,-0.6,0.35],[1641771267315,-0.7,-1.56,-8.2,0.41],[1641771268065,-0.1,-0.89,-0.6,0.35],[1641771268451,-0.4,-0.35,-0.6,0.35]]
```

I need to split this into sub lists as `[1641771267063,-0.63,-0.35,-0.6,0.35] and [1641771267315,-0.7,-1.56,-8.2,0.41]` and so on.

My ultimate goal is to count the numbers inside each of these sets. It has to be 5 every time.

I attempted to write a snippet in Java as shown below. But the list isn't getting splitted. Please help.

```
List<String> inputList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Input));
            int chunkSize = 1;
            List<List<String>> partitionedList = 
ListUtils.partition(inputList, chunkSize);

            for (List<String> list : partitionedList){
                System.out.println("print list "+list);
                System.out.println("list size " +list.size());
            }
```

print list `[[[1641771267063,-0.63,-0.35,-0.6,0.35],[1641771267315,-0.7,-1.56,-8.2,0.41],[1641771268065,-0.1,-0.89,-0.6,0.35],[1641771268451,-0.4,-0.35,-0.6,0.35]]]` 
list size 1

Comment: What is the current output you are getting from running this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you treat your input as arrays of `double`, you can do the following:

```
double[][] input = {{1641771267063d, -0.63, -0.35, -0.6, 0.35}, {1641771267315d, -0.7, -1.56, -8.2, 0.41},
        {1641771268065d, -0.1, -0.89, -0.6, 0.35}, {1641771268451d, -0.4, -0.35, -0.6, 0.35}};

List<List<Double>> partitionedList = Arrays.stream(input)
        .map(subArray -> Arrays.stream(subArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (List<Double> list : partitionedList) {
    System.out.println("print list " + list);
    System.out.println("list size " + list.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Split a list into multiple subLists in Java

I am presuming from the title your source is a List of double values. But it is somewhat unclear because of the erratic placement of square(`[]`) brackets in the list.

Here is one way.  It uses the `subList` method of the `List interface`.

- Use `IntStream` to generate the indices of the list, incrementing by `chunckSize`
- Create a new list of the sublist (sublists are just a view of the original so a new list should be created).
- The conditional for the 2nd object to `subList` ensures that an exception will not be thrown if the original list size is not a multiple of `chuncksize`.  The last list in the list of lists would them be smaller than the rest.

```
// generate some data
List<Double> list = IntStream.range(1, 94)
        .mapToObj(i->(double)i)
        .toList();


int chunckSize = 8;
List<List<Double>> lists = IntStream
        .iterate(0, i -> i < list.size(),
                i -> i += chunckSize)
        .mapToObj(i -> (List<Double>) new ArrayList<>(
                list.subList(i,
                        i + ((i < list.size() - chunckSize) ?
                                chunckSize :
                                list.size() - i))))
        .toList();

lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

For this demo prints

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
[9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0]
[17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0]
[25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0]
[33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0]
[41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0]
[49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0]
[57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0]
[65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0]
[73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0]
[81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0]
[89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0]
```

If by some chance, your source data is a 2 dimensional `ragged double array` you could convert it to a List as follows and then apply the above method.

```
double[][] vals = ....
List<Double> list = Arrays.stream(vals)
        .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream).boxed().toList();
```

And finally, if your arrays are already sized as an array of `double[N][5]` then you can simply convert the array to a `List<List<Double>>` as follows.

```
List<List<Double>> lists = Arrays.stream(vals)
                .map(arr->Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toList())
                .toList();
```

**Updated Answer.**

- first I remove the end double brackets and then split on `],[`
- then I stream those strings and split each one  on `,` converting to doubles and storing in the list.
- then those lists are stored in a main list.

Since one must parse the string to see if the elements are of the correct count, I simply assumed they were and then checked after the fact.

So I streamed the list of lists and as soon as a bad count was detected, printed an error message.

Otherwise, I printed the lists.

```
List<List<Double>> lists = Arrays
        .stream(str.replaceAll("(?:\\[\\[)|(?:\\]\\])", "")
                .split("\\]\\,\\["))
        .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                .map(Double::valueOf).toList())
        .toList();
```

now validate

```
if (lists.stream().anyMatch(lst -> lst.size() != 5)) {
    System.out.println(
            "At least one list does not have 5 elements");
} else {
    lists.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

prints

```
[1.641771267063E12, -0.63, -0.35, -0.6, 0.35]
[1.641771267315E12, -0.7, -1.56, -8.2, 0.41]
[1.641771268065E12, -0.1, -0.89, -0.6, 0.35]
[1.641771268451E12, -0.4, -0.35, -0.6, 0.35]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @WJS @Ervin for your response. Apologies, I was not clear in my question that the input was a String (although in the square braces).

I found the count of numbers in each of the boxed set a little differently to what I initially thought I should do.

I split the string initially on ']' and put the split string into an array.  Then split each of these string on  ',' and then validated if the number of token is equal to 5.

```
String str = "[[1641771267063,-0.63,-0.35,-0.6,0.35],[1641771267315,-0.7,-1.56,-8.2,0.41],[1641771268065,-0.1,-0.89,-0.6,0.35],[1641771268451,-0.4,-0.35,-0.6,0.35]]";
String str_extracted = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

String[] str1 = str_extracted.split("],");
    for (int i=0; i< str1.length ; i++){
        String[] tokens = str1[i].split(",");
        Assert.assertTrue(tokens.length == 5, "string does not have 5 values");
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.